# Date not coming based on order for creating Excel sheets in java

Tags: java, excel, collections

I am using the below code to create a map with date as a key and my dto object as value

```
Map < String, List <DTOObject>> dataMap = new HashMap < String, List <DTOObject>> ();
             for (DTOObject data: datalist) {
                 if (dataMap.get(data.getDate()) == null) {
                     dataMap.put(data.getDate(), new ArrayList <DTOObject>());
                 }
                 dataMap.get(data.getDate()).add(fundData);
             }
```

I am using the key in this map to create my excel sheets inside an excel. I am using the below code to create the date format name for sheet.

```
public static String getPeriodMonth(String periodEndDate) {
    LocalDate localDate;
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
    localDate = LocalDate.parse(periodEndDate, formatter);
    YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.from(localDate);
    return yearMonth.toString();

}
```

But my sheets are not coming in the right order based on dates. It is creating as below.

[image]

How can I make it in the order of date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HashMap` is implemented as a hash table, and there is no ordering on keys or values, this is why you do not get your keys in any order. `TreeMap` is implemented based on red-black tree structure, and it is ordered by the key.

Instead of `Map<K, V> dataMap = new HashMap<>();`, you can use `SortedMap<K, V> dataMap = new TreeMap<>();`

When you iterate `TreeMap` you will get your keys in order.

Try this as a sample:

```
        SortedMap<LocalDateTime, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

        map.put(LocalDateTime.now(), 1);
        Thread.sleep(10);
        map.put(LocalDateTime.now(), 2);
        Thread.sleep(10);
        map.put(LocalDateTime.now(), 3);
        Thread.sleep(10);
        map.put(LocalDateTime.now(), 4);

        for (Map.Entry<LocalDateTime, Integer> m : map.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(m.getKey());
        }
```